# Facebook app is misconfigured

Tags: php, html, facebook, social-networking, fbml

I am working on a facebook app, it takes the oauth from the user. Everything works fine but, When the user reject the popup oauth then it displays:

*"Sorry, the details for F_wp_app cannot be displayed because the app is misconfigured."*

Here is the code for my index.php file

```
include_once 'facebook.php';

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user)
{
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
    require('./wp-blog-header.php');
    ob_end_flush();
}
else
{
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope'=>'publish_stream',
    'redirect_uri'=>'https://apps.facebook.com/226166417548050/'
    ));
    echo "<script> top.location='$loginUrl'</script>";
}
```

I want that if the user rejects the oauth then it is automatically redirected back to the oauth.

Any help would be appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: Did you take out the instantiation of the facebook object for this post? Where you pass in your app id and secret

Comment: @DavidJones... Yes I used app id and secret for the app. But at the same time it is representing that my app is misconfigured

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: Thankyou very much the problem is solved